# Return false doesn't cancel radio buttons click in Chrome when no other value selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I'm trying to cancel a radio button click. I have a jquery click handler like this:

```
$("#myList").on("click","input", function(){

    return false;

});
```

This works fine when there is already a selected value. But if I click a radio button from a group that has no selected value, the return false does not work, and the element that I clicked actually gets selected.

Any clues?

**Edit:**

Here is the fiddle demonstrating the problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/SFZMm/2/

**Edit2:**

Just found out this only happens on chrome :( Firefox and IE work as expected. Maybe a workaround?

Comment: And what is something?

Comment: for the sake of simplicity, something is just a boolean var set before

Comment: @AnoopJoshi html is on the way

Comment: Check out the jsfiddle demo...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, try this [JS_FIDDLE-DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kbAk3/361/)

It detects the click on the parent container. Not the radio button it self.

```
 //listen to click on parent div,span,li for example. 
$("#myList-parent").click(function(){

       alert('You clicked radio!');
        //Now put your logic here. I decide based on the radio button value. 
       if($('input:radio[name=type]:checked').val() == "UnSelectable"){
          alert($('input:radio[name=type]:checked').val());
              return false;    
       }
   });
```

**Update (work around for Chrome): [JS-FIDDLE-DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SFZMm/5/)**
It seems Chrome has issues with `on click` so replace it with  `on mousedown` (*or use both?*):

```
 $("input").on("mousedown",function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            alert('This radio button was checked in mousedown');                
        } else {
            alert('This radio button was not checked in mousedown');
        }                    
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, in my original code I am detecting the click on parent not on element itself. Try this modification of your fiddle and click on the "unselectable" radio, see what happens? http://jsfiddle.net/kbAk3/362/

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following what you mean. the unselectable cannot be selected regardless of the value of 'selectable'. Would you pls explain more about what is the behavior your are expecting?

Comment: I'm expecting not being able to select the unselectable radio button, yet in Chrome, I am able to

Comment: Ok, so my version on Firefox works fine then. I will check chrome now, give me a moment.

Comment: This is  a work around for Chrome. I will integrate it into my answer.  http://jsfiddle.net/vAcpc/75/

Comment: How does this work? I'd rather use the "on" jquery event handler if possible, as it allows me to delegate event handling to parent container, since my html is loaded dynamically it's easier to attach handler to parent element

Comment: Check my update. It's not really different than your code, I just used onmousedown instead of  on click. It seems Chrome has issue with it.

Comment: I guess i'll have to use the mousedown event, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use [change methods for input elements](http://api.jquery.com/change/) instead of click.

```
$("#myList").on("change","input", function(e){
    if(something){
        e.preventDefault();
    } else{
  //for test
   alert('not true');
  }
});
```

Comment: If I use change the event gets fired but return false now doesn't work even for groups that have another element selected...it doesn't stop the radio button from being clicked at all

Comment: try and tell me is that alerting 'not true'?

Comment: check out my fiddle...issue is only happening on chrome, IE and FF are working fine

Comment: The canceling of the radio button click event. Even though I return false, it still gets clicked in Chrome. Check out the fiddle I linked to in Chrome and other browser and you can see issue for yourself

Comment: oh! seems to be bug! but you can use like this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SFZMm/6/

Comment: That doesn't quite achieve what I want. I want to cancel the click, and leave it as it was if it had any value, or just leave it unchecked if it didn't have a value. Your code just sets whatever was checked as unchecked. Thanks for the effort though!